# My installer package throws 3010 or 1641 when run from SCCM. Works fine if i run as admin

Tags: cmd, installshield, sccm, windows-installer

I have a installaer package (mySoftware.exe) which is working fine without any issue when i run manually as admin. But i am getting exit code 3010,1641 when i install the package via SCCM. My code skips the next steps if it gets other than "0" exit code. Right now, my installer consider "0" as Success. Non-Zero are error codes.

Do i need to modify installer script to consider "0","3010","3011","1641","1604" as Success exit code ? Do we need to change anything at SCCM end?

Do i need to consider to add any other exit code as Success? Do we have any other workaround for this issue.

```
mySoftware.exe /s /v" /quiet ADDLOCAL="mySoftwareConfig" /L*v "%mySoftwareLogFile%" /clone_wait

> My installer script has the following actions: 
  1)First uninstall existing package on the system.
> 2. Install the new package.  (Exit code 3010,1641 returns during installing the new package)
> 3. Configure the package.
```

Comment: Does the installer require admin permission to work correctly? What happens if you run in manually without admin permission?

Comment: I works fine without admin access as well. I always go to C:\Windows\System32\Cmd -> and launch the installer form this location like how SCCM use the system user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Reboot***: Those are generally just standard reboot message and you should handle them in your batch file as you suggest yourself.

This is just a mock-up sample (I am no expert at this anymore):

```
msiexec.exe /I Setup.msi ALLUSERS=1 /L*V %MSILOG% /qb-! ADDLOCAL=ALL
if %errorlevel% == 3010 goto REBOOT

<..stuff here..>

:REBOOT
echo MSIEXEC returned exit code 3010 which means that a reboot is required to complete installation >> %LOGFILE%
```

Some info on errorlevel:

- https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743

---

***MSI Error Messages***: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/error-codes

- **`0`** - **`ERROR_SUCCESS`** - The action completed successfully.
- **`1604`** - **`ERROR_INSTALL_SUSPEND`** - Installation suspended, incomplete.
- **`1641`** - **`ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_INITIATED`** - The installer has initiated a restart. This message is indicative of a success.
- **`3010`** - **`ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED`** - A restart is required to complete the install. This message is indicative of a success. This does not include installs where the ForceReboot action is run.

And from other sources:

- **`3011 (0xBC3)`** - [**`ERROR_SUCCESS_RESTART_REQUIRED`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1700-3999-#ERROR_SUCCESS_RESTART_REQUIRED) - The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective until the service is restarted.

Comment: I am writing some flat-file in the << -- Stuff Here --> section after the successful installation of my installer. Since i am getting exit code3010 or 1641, it directly goes to exit and skips mine <<Stuff Here>> section. I wanted to execute <<--Stuff Here --> section though after i get any of the exit code 0,3010,3011,1604,1641 since it is not really a failure on the installer?